# jquery e.stopPropagation prevents returning value to a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax function which, when clicking a button `#createBtn` calls a Spring MVC method to insert data into a table.

```
$('#createBtn').click(function () {
 e.stopPropagation();   
 $.post("/user/add",$('form').serialize(), function(data) {
     if(data==true){
          alert("Im here");
        }
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

For any successful database insert, the method consistently returns a true value.

The Issue is that if the `e.stopPropagation()` is placed before the `$.post()`, a page with the returned value (**true** in this case) is printed.
If the `e.stopPropagation()` is placed anywhere below the `$.post()`, the alert method(s) is/are called but the application throws a integrity constraint violation as the program tries to insert data more than once.

JSP:

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add"></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="masterScreenForm">
   <div class="input-group-append">
      <input type=text name='uname' placeholder="Enter name">
   </div>
   <button class="btn" id="createBtn">Click me</button>
   </div>
</form:form>
```

How do I make the function accept the returned value without the constraint violation?

Comment: If anything your code throws an error that `e` is undefined.

Comment: Show your HTML as well.

Comment: @31piy i have added the JSP. I believe the form was submitted twice because of the action= /user/add. So I removed the /add from it. Now the integrity constraint violation is gone. My issue now is that the POST method is not defined for /user. This can be done, but im more interested in how to insert without refreshing the page.

Comment: you should define button type button else it will submit form when you click it. Then you wont need to add StopPropogation at all.

Comment: even you can try jQuery.submit event handler too.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1) Move Button outside of the form:

```
<form> stuff here </form> <button id="createBtn">Foo</button>
```

If the button is outside the form, it won't submit the form.

2) Stop submit at the button

```
<form> stuff here </form> <button id="createBtn" onclick="return false">Foo</button>
```

Here the button will not submit the form.

3) Don't use a button. Use a div as your "button":

```
<form> stuff here </form> <div id="createBtn">Foo</div>
```

And you can style the div with css to look like a button.

If your stopPropagation is within the return function, it will not work. There's no point in putting it "after" the $.post. But it should work if it's not in the return function. The post return is a different context and the function will return before the post does.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, the cleanest way to do it is to:

1. Remove the `action` from the `<form>`.
2. Change the type of `#createBtn` to `submit`.
3. Handle the form submit event using jQuery.

Refer to the following example:

In your HTML (you may want to eliminate `form:form` here as you're not using the JSTL anymore):

```
<form:form>
   <div class="input-group-append">
      <input type=text name='uname' placeholder="Enter name">
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn" id="createBtn">Click me</button>
</form:form>
```

In your JavaScript:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

  // Prevent form submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // Send the data without refreshing the page
  $.post( ... )
    .then(function(data) {
      if(data == true) {
        alert("Im here");
      }

      alert(data);
    })
});
```

This method triggers sending the data when the form is submitted, rather than when the button is clicked. This way, you can:

1. Hit enter (while having focused to the input element) to submit the form
2. Trigger browser form validation logic (if you have any fields to validate)